Issue with controlling LIFX bulbs in an Alexa skill in Alexa Developer console
I am building an Alexa skill to control LIFX bulbs using the lifxlan Python library. The library works perfectly when running locally on my machine, but when I deploy it via the Alexa Developer Console, it fails to detect the light bulb. It works when testing until I add the line device = devices[0] (if i remove this line, it works so maybe it's not a problem with the package)
image_lambdapy
image_requierements
From what I've read the alexa developer console may not have access to my lan, so it does not detect the light bulb. How can I solve this? If you need more info, please tell me.
